# Magento 2 : Sales Representative Collect Items from catalog

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want functionality or extension where Sales representative collect items from catalog. After collecting all the necessary items, Sales representative send link to individual customer for checkout. Customer will have to click that link and directly checkout with payment information.

Any extension, similar functionality would be helpful.

Thanks
Yagnesh P.

Comment: https://ecommerce.makarovsoft.com/magento-direct-add-to-cart-and-checkout-link-for-magento-2.html

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use "Login as Customer" module.

Scenario would look like:

1. Login as customer
2. collect all data to cart
3. ask customer to re-login
4. ask customer to go directly to checkout.

Other ways will require a bit more development. Here are some options:

- Disable Cart merge upon login, for example.
- Provide link which will clean cart if customer is guest and redirect to login.